# What is the general stance of the Camarilla on the existence of dhampirs?

Tags: lore, world-of-darkness, vampire-the-masquerade, vampire-the-masquerade-5e

Let's say that players are Camarilla agents, and I, as the storyteller, make them aware of the existence of a dhampir (humans born with one of their parents being a thin-blood, and — by V20 rules — are kinda like revenant ghouls with vampire fangs) via an NPC. Let's say that dhampir is a twenty-something-year-old human.

Now, let's suppose said players report it to the Sheriff or the Prince of their city. What is the general stance on the topic that I could use to model my NPCs after? The only source I have that could say something about it is the Beckett journal (*Beckett's Jyhad Diary*), but it seems vague to me on how they would react. This book suggests, that most of the Camarilla basically treat them like they treat thin-bloods. I haven't read *Time of Thin Blood* yet.

We usually use the V5 metaplot for the game, which I guess would change how the stance is, as they changed a lot of things in the sect for 5th edition.

Comment: @Rorp: Have you read "Time of Thin Blood", which is the **main** source for Dhampirs?

Comment: @Trish no I did not, because I didn't purchase it yet. Should I?

Comment: @Rorp Time of Thin Blood is a really good supplement. I do recommend it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Dhampirs exist only in 2 Books <sup>n</sup>

There're only 2 books that have Kindred Dhampirs in them: *Time of Thin Blood*, which is the actual main source, and *Becket's Jyhad Diary*, where there is one mention of them. The *other* Dhampir book is not about Vampires, so can be ignored.

So, let me grab my ToTB to look up what that tells us.

First of all, Vampires aren't suited to have kids in the first place, and the rate of mortality due to the parents (and their surroundings) will mean that almost none will ever get out of childhood:

> With so many perils, it’s all too easy for a dhampir to end
> up abandoned or orphaned at an early age. Dad runs off and
> Mom dies at the hands of the scourge. Or Mom succumbs
> to drug addiction and Dad decides his child will be happier
> “among normal people.” That is, assuming Dad was ever
> told about the baby in the fi rst place. Even if the family is
> intact (for now), their prospects for domestic bliss are slim
> in the World of Darkness. <sup>1</sup>

Now, how does the Vampire society react in general? Well, a Part of the Camarilla doesn't believe they exist, But those that are in the know have to consider them as what they are: either they are an uncontrolled ghoul, or a breach of masquerade. In both cases, the prospects are not rosy and a cull order might be dished out very quickly.

> Dhampirs are a new phenomenon in the World of Darkness. [...]
>
> The existence of the dhampir is
> still contested by cynics, who suspect some kind of millennial
> hoax, but to those who have an inkling of thin-blooded
> oddities, the idea is all too plausible.
>
> At present, a dhampir who falls into the clutches of a full
> vampire will most likely be mistaken for a revenant or a masterless
> ghoul — hardly cause for joy, perhaps, but good fortune indeed
> compared to the lot of the dhampir who is recognized for what she
> truly is. To Camarilla vampires, she is the ultimate Masquerade
> breach: an elemental and irrevocable mingling of Kindred and
> kine. [...] To Sabbat and other
> die-hard Noddists, she is an ominous portent of doom [...]<sup>2</sup>

That's the quite general broad strokes, from which the very same book carves a few exceptions just in the next paragraph - though even those are not too rosy prospects as being deemed a prophet of Gehenna is not good for long term survival.

Now, pages 81 and following have the rules for Dhampirs: you build a Revenant, but instead of a Ghoul you got a 15th generation vampire parent. In the pre-V5 plot, this would make the character at oldest 20, when the first 15th gen vampires appeared. This might need to be adjusted for the V5 timeline.

### So far, V5 has no dhampirs

None of the V5 books published until February 2024 has shown or discussed dhampirs.

---

1. Time of Thin Blood (1999), p.48
2. Time of Thin Blood (1999), p.49

Note: While *Half-Damned Dhampir* (2000) exists it handles *Kuei-Jin* offspring in a Kuei-jin environment, not Kindred offspring. They don't generally exist in areas where the Camarilla has any power: wherever Kuei-jin Dhampirs exist, the power of the night is generally in the hands of the Kuei-jin, and Kindred are killed on sight. Atop that, Kindred wouldn't have a chance to *spot* those as anything different from Kuei-jin.

Comment: Three books—"Half-Damned" is also a thing. https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/2551/HalfDamned-Dhampyr

Comment: @Jadasc which is a Kindred of the East soucebook, to play with not Kindred but Kuei-jin. Those Dhampirs are the offspwing of Kuei-Jin, so technically not related to Kindred at all.

Answer (score 6):

If you're informing "the Prince" or "the Sheriff" then *they're* the one that's going to react - not "the Camarilla".

Vampire is fundamentally a game of intrigue, where literally everyone is out for themselves.  The specific individual they have just reported to will have biases, preconceptions, and, in particular, goals of their own.  They will act as they themselves would act, on being informed of such a thing... and if they told someone else, that person would react as *they* would react.  You don't get to how "the Camarilla" reacts unless it becomes public knowledge, and in a game so steeped in secrets as Vampire, that's not likely to happen quickly (or, perhaps, at all).